# jquery .append() method producing unwanted result

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, api-design

I'm working on a project using Wikipedia's API. I have been able to successfully load the API's data.
 However, here is the problem I try to load the API's result into the DOM when an input value is submitted, but each time I try to submit a new value the result is gets appended to the initial result from the first input search.

Here is a fiddle which may show what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/aonz929f/1/

```
    for( var key in data.query.pages){
        //loop through the JSON data 
       }

$("#result").append(htmlContent)/// Then I used the append method to return each returned result to the DOM
```

Comment: That is what [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is supposed to do. If you want to replace you could use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead. Is `htmlContent` a string with HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the already existing html before appending new one, like this:

```
$("#result").html("")
for( var key in data.query.pages){
   $("#result").append(("<p>" + data.query.pages[key].title) + "</p>")
   //etc..        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works and I think it explains it better